# img position: fixed; does not move with screen when changing screen size

Tags: html, css, css-position, window-size

I've placed a "shadow" (just a png file made on procreate) behind a set of three icons so they're visible against my background. The icons are position: fixed; and so is the shadow (position:fixed;), but the shadow does not shift its position when I adjust the screen size on the X plane (change screen's width). I'd like for the img with class "helpbar" to move with the icons when the width of the screen is adjusted.

I'm brand new and self-taught w/ HTML/CSS. Let me know if I excluded any details that may be relevant.

TL;DR

***DESIRED BEHAVIOR: img class "helpbar" should move with icons at the top of the page.

***PROBLEM: img class "helpbar" does not move when window's width is decreased.

[window width is decreased, icons move, img with class "helpbar" does not move with icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbM5l.png)

[How icons and img with class "helpbar" should look irrespective of window size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id7ph.png)

```
    <body id="body" class="light">

<div id="groupHead">
  <img type="image" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="helpbar" src="Shuffle_SHADOW.png">

  <div class="shapes">
    <img id="handy-hover" viewBox="0 0 24 24" src="311032.svg" alt="HANDY_SVG" fill="none" width="24px" height="24px">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12"/>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M12 0L14.6942 8.98278H23.4127L16.3593 14.5344L19.0534 23.5172L12 17.9656L4.94658 23.5172L7.64074 14.5344L0.587322 8.98278H9.30583L12 0Z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.helpbar{
  position:fixed;
  transform: translate(390px, -405px) scale(.39);
  transition: var(--transition);
  overflow-x: visible;
}

#groupHead {
  overflow-x: visible;
  position:relative;
  width:calc(100vh - 100px);

}

.shapes svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  transition: var(--transition);
  fill: var(--clr-primary);
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
.shapes svg:first-child {
  right: 100px;
}
.shapes svg:nth-child(2) {
  right: 150px;
}
.shapes svg:last-child {
  right: 200px;
}

.shapes img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  transition: var(--transition);
  fill: var(--clr-primary) !important;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  right: 100px;

}


.light {
  --clr-primary: #000;
  --clr-secondary: black;
  --position: relative;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  --clr-dots: #00000066;
  z-index: 3;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--clr-secondary);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  padding:.5;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

I've tried screwing around with the position property, but I haven't had much luck...not sure what the fix is after poking around the stacks :(. SOS.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add any missing information. Do not add any code inside a comment which should be in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for the input! You can tell, this is my first post. I'll update my question.

Comment: Will do--thanks!